Wallet tracking problems
Im trying to convert my existing wallet tracker to websocket based instead of polling. Im building a simple realtime wallet tracker for myself with helius i have the maxed out plan. I looked into geyser enhanced websockets as well.
What is the best way to simply get the swaps done on the account that trade a pumpfun/raydium coin. Everyway i do always gets all the small transactions involved. I simply want the swap, the mint, swap amount in sol and how mych tokens bought or sold. Anyone figure this out using websockets and helius?

You should check this repo out: wallet tracker
Helius will provide u with all the data, u have to format and clean out the data that is irrelevant to your application
